# Azure Function: azure function publish password attention required

Tags: function, azure, cloud, azure-functions

I have problem publishing my azure function. It said Password Attention Required. It must be the password missing in the profile setting. Is there a way to edit the existing profile and passed in the password

Comment: Try to delete the profile and make a new one. Refer to this [issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f0c19f6e-0f89-404a-9524-aaba7ebf92e1/how-to-re-configure-authentication-when-publishing-in-visual-studio?forum=AzureFunctions).

Comment: Looks like a authentication thing, Try logging out and re-logging in from vs